# Visual Studio, Newtonsoft.Json - nuget package updated, but old dll version is still in bin

Tags: .net, dll, nuget

I've run :

```
update-package -reinstall newtonsoft.json
```

which has successfully updated the dll in my 'packages' folder to v9.0.1

The reference in my project is showing v9.0.0, however when I rebuild, I still have the old version of newtonsoft.json (v4.5).

I can only refresh this by deleting the dll and rebuilding, but why do I need to do this?

My understanding is that the dll 'refresh' files are no longer needed by nuget, although I've been unable to find any definitive resource on the mechanics of nuget in Visual Studio 2015. Any suggestions on where I can find this, or why the refresh isn't being done automatically?

Comment: Wouldn't Rebuild or Clean -> Build solve the solution ?

Comment: As I've stated, I did initially rebuild.